# Layout problem with large striked text in the comment section

Tags: bug, design

The problem can be observed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/650405

The comment section stretches over the right sidebar.

Bonus points for figuring out what else can reproduce the layout problem.

Note: The problem exists while browsing with firefox, but no problem in chrome.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254786/comments-on-question-can-break-the-page-layout

Comment: ...send bonus points to answers at MSE: [Why are comments overlapping the sidebar?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154788/165773)