# A comment using underscores breaks page layout

Tags: bug, comments

Using a lot of underscores in a comment `_` breaks the page layout and prints the text out-of-bounds (justifying the name of the website :-) ).

Tested on Firefox 38, Opera 30, and Internet Explorer 11, as seen in this question: [save expanded macro result before it is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433672/save-expanded-macro-result-before-it-is-undefined/)

Link to the problematic comment: 
[save expanded macro result before it is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433672/save-expanded-macro-result-before-it-is-undefined/35433886#comment58571334_35433886)

And replicated here today: [Deleting a Node in BST in a non recursive way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539958/deleting-a-node-in-bst-in-a-non-recursive-way/35540117#35540117)

Comment: Okay - it's been seen and screenshot - no need to show how much "fun" it is on MSO as well please...

Comment: `preg_replace('/(_{5,})/','$1<wbr>',$comment)`

Comment: @DJDavid98 it isn't so much specifically the underscore, its basically single 'words' becoming way too long if I interpret the test results correctly.

Comment: It's the price one has to pay for using tables to display comments _(looking at you, SO)_.

Comment: [A dup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254786/comments-on-question-can-break-the-page-layout), also showing the fun on MSO ; ).

Comment: @DJDavid98 SO isn't written in that mongrel language.  Arf.